# SysML - What are the minimum elements needed to show a specified block satisfies a requirement?

Tags: sysml

I want to draw a SysML diagram that summarizes I have a system, and expresses that it includes a safety mechanism such that it can detect & handle 'serious failures'.

What are the minimum elements I have to use to show this? So far I have:

1. Req (Requirements) diagram.
2. System modeled as a «block» element who name is "System".
3. Requirement modeled as a «requirement» element, with descr = "Can detect & handle 'serious failures' etc."
4. Requirement satisfaction modeled as a «satisfy» relationship going from the "System" to the Requirement.

Is this enough? (Hope so...)

Or do I, as I expect, have to include some explicit sub-block inside "System", where the sub-block's name is something like "SafetyMechanism"?

And if the block alone is not sufficient to be used with a «satisfy» relationship, then what other relationship would be appropriate to draw going from the block to the requirements to make it mean what I want it to mean.

[image]